# SQL subquery in SELECT clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated

I'm trying to find admin activity within the last 30 days.

The accounts table stores the user data (username, password, etc.)

At the end of each day, if a user had logged in, it will create a new entry in the player_history table with their updated data. This is so we can track progress over time.

accounts table:

| id | username | admin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Michael | 4 |
| 2 | Steve | 3 |
| 3 | Louise | 3 |
| 4 | Joe | 0 |
| 5 | Amy | 1 |

player_history table:

| id | user_id | created_at | playtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2021-04-03 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-04-04 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | 2021-04-05 | 15 |
| 3 | 4 | 2021-04-10 | 20 |
| 4 | 5 | 2021-04-11 | 20 |
| 5 | 1 | 2021-05-12 | 40 |
| 6 | 2 | 2021-05-13 | 55 |
| 7 | 3 | 2021-05-17 | 65 |
| 8 | 4 | 2021-05-19 | 75 |
| 9 | 5 | 2021-05-23 | 30 |
| 10 | 1 | 2021-06-01 | 60 |
| 11 | 2 | 2021-06-02 | 65 |
| 12 | 3 | 2021-06-02 | 67 |
| 13 | 4 | 2021-06-03 | 90 |

The following query

`` SELECT a.`username`, SEC_TO_TIME((MAX(h.`playtime`) - MIN(h.`playtime`))*60) as 'time' FROM `player_history` h, `accounts` a WHERE h.`created_at` > '2021-05-06'  AND h.`user_id` = a.`id`  AND a.`admin` > 0 GROUP BY h.`user_id` ``

Outputs this table:

Note that this is just admin activity, so Joe is not included in this data.

from 2021-05-06 to present (yy-mm-dd):

| username | time |
| --- | --- |
| Michael | 00:20:00 |
| Steve | 00:10:00 |
| Louise | 00:02:00 |
| Amy | 00:00:00 |

As you can see this from data, Amy's time is shown as 0 although she has played for 10 minutes in the last month. This is because she only has 1 entry starting from 2021-05-06 so there is no data to compare to. It is 0 because 10-10 = 0.

Another flaw is that it doesn't include all activity in the last month, basically only subtracts the highest value from the lowest.

So I tried fixing this by comparing the highest value after 2021-05-06 to their most previous login before the date. So I modified the query a bit:

`` SELECT a.`Username`, SEC_TO_TIME((MAX(h.`playtime`) - (SELECT MAX(`playtime`) FROM `player_history` WHERE a.`id` = `user_id` AND `created_at` < '2021-05-06'))*60) as 'Time' FROM `player_history` h, `accounts` a WHERE h.`created_at` >= '2021-05-06' AND h.`user_id` = a.`id` AND a.`admin` > 0 GROUP BY h.`user_id` ``

So now it will output:

| username | time |
| --- | --- |
| Michael | 00:50:00 |
| Steve | 00:50:00 |
| Louise | 00:52:00 |
| Amy | 00:10:00 |

But I feel like this whole query is quite inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There are *lots* of flaws with this code, starting with the fact that it is syntactically incorrect because the `select` and `group by` are inconsistent.  I would suggest that you provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I've edited the original post @GordonLinoff

Comment: I've already edited my original post? @Strawberry

Comment: Yes. We can see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `lag()`:

```
SELECT a.username,
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(h.playtime - COALESCE(h.prev_playtime, 0))) as time
FROM accounts a JOIN
     (SELECT h.*,
             LAG(playtime) OVER (PARTITION BY u.user_id ORDER BY h.created_at) as prev_playtime
      FROM player_history h
     ) h
     ON h.user_id = a.id
WHERE h.created_at > '2021-05-06' AND
      a.admin > 0
GROUP BY a.username;
```

In addition to the `LAG()` logic, note the other changes to the query:

- The use of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- The use of consistent columns for the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.
- The removal of single quotes around the column alias.
- The removal of backticks; they just clutter the query, making it harder to write and to read.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks a lot. Good explanation aswell.

Comment: Just curious, how long did this take you to do?